# Circuit for determining the dc mean of a wave-form

Tags: dc

I need to find the DC mean of a waveform whose maximum and minimum values will vary. The input signal has a frequency range of 0 - 3Hz, and will have a voltage range of 0 - 5V. I would like to find the DC mean of the waveform after the waveform has gone through three cycles. The waveform I want to find the DC mean of is shown below:

[image: Blood pressure waveform]

Can anyone suggest a circuit for me to implement this solution please?

---

**Edit - RM::
I'm adding this "description". Please delete/ amend as appropriate.**

The requirement relates to blood pressure measurement.
 Each cycle is a pulse or heartbeat period long - typically around 1 second / 60 BPM (Beats Per Minute) but can be as long as 2 seconds / 30 BPM or as fast as 1/4 second / 240 BPM (although values at either of those extremes would be very rare.) (eg Super athlete resting and super athlete under utter extreme exertion.)

Ideally the system will acquire the mean value after a single valid cycle and,
 chose 1 -

- Update it on a cycle by cycle basis thereafter
- Track it continually over the last single whole cycle so it is up to data instantaneously for the last pulse period.
- Track it continually over the last N whole cycles so it is up to data instantaneously for the last N pulse periods.
- Other ...

Comment: Ah - diagram is much better. Ad I note the magic labels "Systolic" and "Diastolic", which add extra information about time scale required IF they are in fact specific to this problem.

Comment: @Russell: The time scale at the bottom of the graph is also a good clue to the time scale.

Comment: Getting an accurate average at such a low frequency in analog is going to require huge-valued components - the problem as restated just screams "do it in software!"

Comment: @Russel McMahon - Yes, they are specific to the problem I am trying to solve. I am trying to get the DC mean that will represent the average human blood pressure.

Comment: I liked @Bitrex 's answer which he deleted. It seemed to give one possible complete solution. ie sample digitally, compute max and min points, calculate average between, update result as required. A rolling last cycle or last N cycles average is a possibility.

Comment: @Bitrex- Unfortunately, I can't use the ADC of the MCU because it is already being used in another function module. I like the digital sampling though, so thanks.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - yes - client seems to be alive and in OK health :-). Pulse rate of ~ 80 ppm. BP of 118/67 looks "rather good". Biggest indicator of early cardiac mortality is allegedly (by some) Psystolic-Pdiastolic as it reflects arterial flexibility. So this person is arguably not as healthy as a BP 120/80 on that measure - but 67 is still nicely low. Too low and you may faint if they stand up fast :-).

Comment: @DBrown What type of microcontroller are you using?  Many microcontrollers only have one ADC, but this ADC can often be multiplexed across multiple pins, so it can still be used to sample multiple signals.

Comment: @Bitrex- I am using an PIC18F452 for this particular project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy.  This is exactly what a low pass filter does.  You do have to decide over what time scale you want to find the mean.  For short time, you want to get the average.  Over long times, you want to let this "average" vary.  Only you can say where this transistion should be.  Once you know that transition period, you use that to adjust the time constant of the low pass filter.

There are many types of low pass filters, but simple R-C should do well enough.  Cascading several R-C filters will allow a more abrupt transition between the fast "find the average" and slow "follow the average" regimes.

If you provide more specifics, I can provide a more specific answer.

### Added:

Now that you've added significantly more detail, it is clear a simple analog low pass filter will not suffice.  In particular, it's not going to meet the requirement to find the average each cycle and after only one cycle.

There are analog techniques like a gated integrator, but this will be much simpler in a microcontroller.  You say your micro has no additional A/D input, but that is a non-argument.  First, you can certainly get one that has more A/D inputs.  Second, since you were willing to add analog electronics you can just as well add a micro dedicated to this task alone.  It can then report the average over a simple digital interface, like a UART, to the main micro.  Third, you originally asked for a analog solution, so how did you expect to get this information into the main micro without a A/D converter?  If a analog signal proportional to the average has to go elsewhere, then such a signal can be easily produced by the additional micro that does the averaging.  Worst case you get a circuit that takes the analog pulse signal in and produces the analog average out as you originally asked for.  It just happens the averaging will be performed digitally in a microcontroller inside the black box.

Fortunately your frequency range is quite low, so is easily handled by even a small micro.  The signal may have meaningful components up to 1 kHz, but since you want the average you can apply some analog low pass filtering and thereby decrease the sample rate even further.  In this case loosing some of the high frequencies won't hurt since they don't contribute to the average anyway.  With the high frequencies attenuated, it will also be easier to identify individual cycles by looking for peaks or zero crossings.  Note that your original waveform as you show it has multiple local maxima and zero crossings.  These are strictly due to the harmonics of the signal.  With the harmonics reduced, you should be able to get a single local minimum/maximum and zero crossing each direction per cycle.  The firmware computes the average from one positive zero crossing to the next, for example.

I'd probably sample at 1 kHz.  Put two poles of analog low pass filtering at about 200 Hz before the A/D.  You will probably need to buffer the result to get a low enough impedance for the A/D input of the micro.  Once inside the micro, I'd add another couple of poles of low pass filtering with a lower rolloff frequency, like in the 50-100 Hz range.  This is to guarantee a single positive zero crossing per cycle.  This may attenuate the input signal, but by using extra fraction bits in the micro no information will be lost.

Then it's simply finding the average each cycle.  At each positive zero crossing, clear a accumulator and a counter.  Each sample, add the sample value into the accumulator and increment the counter by 1.  Next zero crossing divide the accumulated value by the count to get the average in the previous cycle, then do it all again.  If this average needs to be reported as a analog signal, then use it to drive a PWM output, which is externally low pass filtered.

Comment: See edits to question for more details.

Answer (score 3):

To attempt to do this "well" in the analog domain could become complicated.  As I mentioned above, you'll need a way of resetting the op amp integrator, so that means a timer of some sort and a way of discharging the integrating capacitor, like a triggered JFET or MOSFET across the integrating capacitor.  You'll also need a sample-and-hold cicuit to sample the integrator output at the end of the integration time and hold it while the next value is being integrated.

On the other hand, it would be easy to implement your entire circuit using a 75 cent microcontroller, like the ATTiny13A.  Just apply your waveform (through whatever input voltage-division/protection network you desire) to the microcontroller's AD converter.  Sample the input to a buffer in software, long enough to get a full cycle, and then every so often calculate divide the sum of the samples in the buffer by the number and there, you have your average value.  Use the onboard PWM to convert this value back to analog (at a MUCH higher frequency so it's easier to fitler than a 3 Hz signal.) The tiny13 also has an onboard comparator, so you can then take your average value, which is now a DC voltage, and apply it to one of the comparator pins along with your original waveform.  An interrupt will be triggered every time the comparator toggles, if that's what you want, and you can then generate pulses or whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an integrator will do? http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_8/11.html

You can integrate and use the max value as your "average"?

Comment: @Misha- Thanks, but doesn't the integrator add up all the instantaneous voltage values to get a total value, including the maximum value of the waveform? I need the average, so that I can compare it to the original waveform to get pulses using an comparator. And how do I go about calculating the resistor and capacitor values for the integrator? Finally, what factors should I consider when choosing an op-amp for the integrator design?

Comment: @Misha an op amp integrator outside a feedback loop will rail.  There needs to be some means of resetting the integrator for each "time slice."

Comment: @Bitrex - What do you mean, for each "time slice" and by railing? Could you please explain?

Comment: In the absence of information of response time etc - your requirement as stated is about perfectly met by a capacitor with 1 side grounded and a resistor from Vin to capacitor. Capacitor volage long term IS the DC mean. | If you want a solution which closely matches your need you will need to provide substantially more information. At present your description is broad enough that several incompatible specialist answers could  fall within the general description.

Comment: @D Brown I'm assuming you want a circuit that has a faster response time and greater performance than the simple RC circuit Russell mentioned.  An op-amp integrator might be a start, but if you just connect an op-amp integrator to a waveform that has a DC component it will integrate...and integrate..and integrate forever, until limited by some external factor like the supply voltage.  The output voltage will then sit near the supply rail, which is not what you want.  That means that the integrator needs to be "reset" every so often.

Comment: @Russell McMahon - See edits to question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement is to determine mean value with a total sampling time of about 15 seconds.

A digital microcontroller etc solution with an ADC input would allow a close to perfect solution that met most of the possible alternative needs. This would allow an ad hoc solution NOT based on any classic filter algorithm. Or ...

---

If you are monitoring pulse long term - say minutes + then a multi pole low pass filter will do this well. Say 6+ pole Butterworth. Good "attack" time and relatively "steady" wrt pulse variation. This could use digital or analog implementation. In the time available this can be made to work "OK" but a digital solution is far more flexible.

=======================

I liked @Bitrex 's answer which he deleted.
 It's essentially what I suggested above and gives one possible complete solution.- ie

- sample digitally,
  compute max and min points,
  calculate average between max and min
  update result as required.

A rolling last cycle or last N cycles average is a possibility.
 Complexities such as eg change of pulse rate varying cycle length can be handled by software.

Missing so far is the required acquisition time and the desired or acceptable update raes.
 Both are important.

Compare systems which:

- Are For clinical use where it can stabilise over seconds to 10-'s of seconds and then tracks a users blood pressure with a slow change in mean acceptable (say, example only,  10+ seconds to stabilise to within 5% after a step change) would be quite different from
- Are needed to acquire and track pressure in a cuff as it was pumped up and track pressure as cuff pressure was released. Or
- Can be applied in seconds, stabilise, be read and released in say 10-20 seconds overall. Or
- Take a stable value over any one cycle.

Digitally it's "easy" - knowing the problem and acceptable parameters is the hardest part. So far we still don't.

---

**We seem to be almost there with specification.**

Say 5 to 30 cycles.
 Presumably (in the absence of information) you want a number of good cycles where mean is known so you want fast attack and fantastic settling.
 I'd say an N pole Butterworth will do OK where N is as large as you find you need BUT given the relatively demanding task of doing this well, if all ADC's are taken I'd suggest an extra microcontroller may be acceptable.

These are examples of what can be had for what $

Under $US0.60/1000 with 10 bit ADC

- [MC9RS08KA8](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/data_sheet/MC9RS08KA8.pdf)

$1.46/1000 with <= 14 bit ADC, 9 bt DAC, ... !!!

- Cypress PSOC [CY8C24123A](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=31677)

    -

Comment: McMahon - Thanks, but I want to monitor it for a time period of 10-15 seconds.

Comment: @DBrown - we seem to be almost there :-). That's say 5 to 30 cycles. Presumably (in the absence of information) you want a number of good cycles where mean is known so you want fast attack and fantastic settling. I'd say an N pole Butterworth will do OK where N is as large as you find you need BUT given the relatively demanding task of doing this well, f all ADC's are taken I'd suggest an extra microcontroller may be acceptable.

Comment: I deleted it because I realized I really didn't fully understand the OP's requirements.  Since things are more clear now, and it seems the original post wasn't too far off I will add it back for posterity.